# Pandas Groupby: How to get distinct Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Trying to get distinct values for columns after grouping; but am getting a total sum 
groupby is dropping object distinction and losing leading zeros for column

df = pd.read_csv("trial.txt",sep='|',converters={'zip':str},keep_default_na=True,low_memory=False)

Data:

```
Emp State   Zip      Jan feb mar 

Int  NY    11111      1   0   1

int  NY    11111      1   1   0

int  NC    09999      2   2   0

int  ON    NH443     2   2   2
```

after

```
df2 = df.groupby("Zip").count()
```

df2 for zip my output for zip = 11111 
i'll have the output for all 12 months show 2 2 2.
    Were I would expect 2 1 1
and zip 09999 shows as 9999.

How what is wrong about the grouping to not get distinct column values. 
     Have account for non-null values (there are no nulls). Column value is only (0 , 1 ,2)

Comment: Could you add an example for the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`count` returns the count of each group, excluding missing values.  That means that a value of zero would also be included in the count.  To only count positive values, you can apply a lambda function that sums the count of values greater than zero.

```
>>> df.groupby('Zip')[['Jan', 'feb', 'mar']].apply(lambda x: x.gt(0).sum())
       Jan  feb  mar
Zip                 
09999    1    1    0
11111    2    1    1
NH443    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start from why *Zip* column is read as *int*.

Note the subtle difference:

- Third column name in the source file is *Zip*, with **capital** *Z*.
- In your code you put *converters={'zip': str}*, with column name
  starting with **lower case** *z*.

Change it to *converters={'Zip': str}* and the column in question will
be read as *string*.

Another, maybe better solution is to pass *dtype={'Zip': object}* instead.
I wrote *better* because no conversion is actually needed.
It is enough just to specify the column type.

I performed also additional check, i.e. I changed *Zip* in the last row
from *NH443* to *88443*.

So even if this column in the source file contains only digits (in all rows),
its type will be *object*, meaning actually *string*.

And now let's look at what is actual result of your code:

When you run `df2 = df.groupby('Zip').count()`, the result is:

```
       Emp  State  Jan  Feb  Mar 
Zip                              
09999    1      1    1    1     1
11111    2      2    2    2     2
88443    1      1    1    1     1
```

Note the description of *count* function (*GroupBy* variant),
which reads: *Compute **count** of group, excluding missing values*.
As you didn't pass any column list, this count is computed for
all columns.

So your code does'n generate distinct values, but instead it **counts**
non-null values along each column in each group.

If you want what you wrote in the title, i.e. a **list** of
**distinct values**, for each column (not their counts), run:

```
df.groupby('Zip').agg(lambda col: np.sort(col.unique()).tolist())
```

This time the result is:

```
         Emp State  Jan     Feb    Mar 
Zip                                    
09999  [Int]  [NC]  [2]     [2]     [0]
11111  [Int]  [NY]  [1]  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
88443  [Int]  [ON]  [2]     [2]     [2]
```

E.g. group *11111* contains in *Feb* and *Mar* columns
two distinct values: *0* and *1*.

In all other cases (for your sample data) each column
in each group contains a **single** distinct value,
so corresponding lists contain only a **single** element.